# Interpreting results from a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{pmatrix}t&1&1\\1&t&1\\1&1&t\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
Is a linear system. Find the values of t for which the system has a unique solution, infinitely many soluionts and no solution. Row reduced echelon form yields:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{t+2}\\\frac{1}{t+2}\\\frac{1}{t+2}\end{pmatrix}$$
I am not sure how to interpret this. I am unsure between 2 options: either the system has no solution at $t=-2$ and there are infinitely many unique solutions for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (not ${-2}$). Or (the one I am more confident about) is that there are infinitely many solutions at $t=-2$, no solutions at $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ and infinitely many unique solutions as before.

Comment: Hm, what happens when $t = 1$?

Comment: $x_1=x_2=x_3=\frac{1}{3}$. Why?

Comment: Or 1/2, 1/4, 1/4. Or 1, 0, 0. Or 2, -3, 2. Or ...

Comment: I don't get it. You get the general solution $x_1=x_2=x_3=\frac{1}{t+2}$, how do you get those answers from?

Comment: You row-reduced correctly, but forgot that this required dividing by $t-1$.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the steps described below.  Note that we divide twice in order to row reduce: once by $(t-1)$, and once by $-(t +2)$.  Thus, this sequence of steps does **not** work when $t = -2$ or $t = 1$.  So, we must handle those cases separately.

Verify that when $t = 1$, we have infinitely many solutions while when $t = -2$, we have no solutions.

In particular, when $t = 1$, the row reduction is simply
$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1
} \to 
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
}
$$
indicating infinitely many solutions.

---

### Row Reduction Steps:

[image: Row reduction steps]

[image: Row reduction steps]

[image: Row reduction steps]

Answer (score 1):

The row reduction can be performed as
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
t & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & t & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & t & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & t & 1 \\
1 & t & 1 & 1 \\
t & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & t & 1 \\
0 & t-1 & 1-t & 0 \\
0 & 1-t & 1-t^2 & 1-t
\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
&\text{(1) for $t\ne1$}\\[2ex]
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & t & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1-t & 1-t^2 & 1-t
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & t & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2-t-t^2 & 1-t
\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
&\text{(2) for $t\ne-2$}\\[2ex]
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & t & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1/(t+2)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Thus the system has surely unique solution for $t\ne1$ and $t\ne-2$ and the solution is readily seen to be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1/(t+2)\\1/(t+2)\\1/(t+2)\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that this is just one solution because $t$ is supposed to be a fixed number. You have “infinitely many systems”, one for each value of $t$, but each one has one solution (when $t\ne1$ and $t\ne-2$).

If $t=-2$, the matrix before stating condition (2) becomes
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the system has no solution.

If $t=1$, the matrix before stating condition (1) becomes
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the system has infinitely many solution.